# What is the difference between "selector:hover" and "selector :hover"

Tags: css, hover

I have this html code:

```
<div class="nav">
            <div class="buttons"><a href="">Home</a></div>
            <div class="buttons"><a href="">Band</a></div>
            <div class="buttons"><a href="">Tour</a></div>
            <div class="buttons"><a href="">Contact</a></div>
            <div class="dropdownmore">
                <button class="buttons" title="More">
                    More
                </button>
                <div class="morebuttons"><a href="" >Merchandise</a></div>
                <div class="morebuttons"><a href="" >Extras</a></div>
                <div class="morebuttons"><a href="" >Media</a></div>    
            </div>
        </div>
```

and I css for them:

```
.nav  :hover a{
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    line-height: 46px;
}
```

1. When I hover to the nav then only the buttons I hovered is changed. I don't understand why only the buttons I hovered is changed. I haven't use space before hover like that. Please explain it! Thank you very much

Comment: The space before `:hover` means the same as space between any other selectors.

Answer (score -2):

I don't really catch what you are trying to ask, but here are answers based on what i catch from your question :

1. If you want your links to change when it gets hovered, then change your css to this :

   `.nav :hover { color: white; background-color: white; line-height: 46px; }`
2. If you want all your links styled without getting hovered, then change your css to this :

   `.nav a { color: black; background-color: white; line-height: 46px; }`